# Overheads of a database compared to a file of structs?

Tags: database, performance, file, database-performance, file-format

Say I have a file that is filled by just doing buffered writes of the same struct type over and over again into a file on local disk (literally copying the struct as is, nonportably straight into the file buffer). Say also I only ever read this file sequentially from beginning to end, all the data. I only ever have one writer to a file, but may have many simultaneous readers, but writing is never concurrent with reading (the file is always complete before anyone reads it). "Schema" evolution is just handled by a version number at the beginning of the file so you know how big the structs are.

I can go to any database's website and see a gigantic feature list. What I can't find is a list of all the overheads -- what are all the extra steps the database has to do to provide that big feature set, compared to the flat file and how much do they usually impact performance? Assuming each struct instance was instead a row in a table in the database, if I can get X throughput writing to disk and Y throughput reading from disk with the file version, what is a *reasonable expectation* for throughput to and from the database? 0.9*X and 0.9*Y? Worse? Better?

To get the ball rolling, the costs I can anticipate (but don't know the real magnitude of) are two phase commit causing extra writes, indexing causing extra writes, and extra overhead to start reading and writing in the form of connecting to the database and sending the query. Possibly also waiting for replication (in the file case you would just count on whatever regular backup mechanism you have, e.g. nightly rsync).

Comment: If your application works using a local file, then that is a fine solution.  If you need ACID properties, security, scalability, and so on, then you should consider a database.

Comment: @Gordon_Linoff sure, but what I'm asking is how much of a performance trade off there is and what causes those trade offs

Comment: So what you are describing is the equivalent to a 1 row table?

Comment: @BobC No, I believe what I'm describing is equivalent to an N row table. Since I am writing N struct instances. Each member of the struct would be a column in the table.

Comment: So in this "database system" you are creating, does each reader always read all the rows?